# How to show image emerging out of a div

Tags: css

[image: Phone passing from the surface area of a div]

Hello! I want to create the below thing. The approach that I am thinking of is to first place the div, rotate it 45°, place the phone inside that div, and give overflow hidden to the div

**Attempt**: I have tried the below code. But can't seem to figure out how to clip the image from the bottom

```scss
.phone-box {
    background: linear-gradient(309.89deg, #FFF807 -147%, #00A0FD 170.59%);
    rotate: -45deg;
    position: relative;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    border-radius: 12px;

    .phone {
        poition: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -25%);
        width: 100%
        rotate: 45deg;
        transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="phone-box">
    <img class="phone" src="assets/images/advertise/phone.png"/>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Any piece of code you want to share with us?

Comment: Please add enough code to create a [mre]